# Pointer of Pointers in MATLAB Mexfile Template

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

For some context, I am familiar with C programming (not an expert but a daily user) and also MATLAB. I have used C++ minimally and not recently.

I had recently started looking into the MEX functionality of MATLAB as I hadn't ever looked at it before. While I was working through a [basic example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html) I noticed something I had not seen before in the entry point function `mexFunction`, copy/pasted from the docs below.

The output and input arguments are returned as pointers of type `mxArray` but with an empty  bracket (e.g., `mxArray *plhs[]`). Coming from C I would have just expected `mxArray *plhs`. I can also understand you might want to return multiple types like scalars, matrices, etc. so maybe you want a pointer to pointers so wouldn't you do `mxArray **plhs`?

From this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350461/c-asterisk-and-bracket-operators-used-together) I understand the syntax `mxArray *plhs[]` means an array of pointers. Is that different than doing `mxArray **plhs`?

```matlab
/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
/* variable declarations here */

/* code here */
}
```

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746434/double-pointer-vs-array-of-pointersarray-vs-array

Comment: `mxArray *plhs[]` declares `plhs` to be an array of `mxArray*` pointers. `mxArray *plhs` would be an array of `mxArray` objects, a different thing entirely. `mxArray *plhs[]` is indeed equivalent, in the function parameter list, to `mxArray **plhs`

Answer (score 2):

In `int arr[...]` arr *is* (represents) the address of the 1st element of arr.

In `int *p` p contains an address to an int (actually, similarly to arr, p *is* (represents) the address where an address to an int is, but that's maybe confusing).

When indexing arr, `arr[i]` and `p[i]`, the compiler performs a similar calculation

- `arr[i]` => `*(arr + i*sizeof(int))`
- `p[i]` => `*((p) + i*sizeof(int))`

if there is a slight difference here, is that the compiler uses directly the address of arr, while it takes the value of p (there is an indirection). If `p = arr`

```
arr -> int0 int1 int2 ...
p -> (address of arr) -> int0 int1 int2
```

but practically that indirection does not affect how the code is written.

Answering @CrisLuengo:

> “*if there is a slight difference here, is that the compiler uses directly the address of arr, while it takes the value of p (there is an indirection).*” I don’t understand what you are saying here. The two are identical and produce identical code.

Actually no ; these pieces of code

```
int arr[5];                      int *p;
int x = arr[1];                  int x = p[1];
```

the `int x = ...` produces the following assembly

```
# arr.c:6: int x = arr[1];            # p.c:6: int x = p[1];
movl -28(%rbp), %eax # arr[1], tmp84  movq -8(%rbp), %rax # p, tmp84
movl %eax, -36(%rbp) # tmp84, x       movl 4(%rax), %eax  # MEM[(int *)p_2(D) + 4B], tmp85
                                      movl %eax, -12(%rbp) # tmp85, x
```

Please note that in this particular example, if the code is compiled with optimizations, the compiler may be able to skip the step of reading the value of `p` and directly use the address of `arr`, resulting in similar assembly code for accessing `arr[1]` and `p[1]`. However, in general, accessing an array element is typically faster than accessing an element through a pointer due to the additional step of retrieving the pointer's value.

---

A difference, is that arr *being* an address, is fixed (`arr++` and `arr = arr2` are illegal). But p contains a value (an address) that can be changed, incremented etc.

And interesting aspect of the similarity is when passing arr to a function

```
void f(int a[]) { ... }
f(arr);
```

The function f takes a parameter which is variable. f can take arr, arr2, ... Thus `a` in f is treated like a pointer to an int

```
void f(int a[]) { int y = *a++ ; int x ; a = &x; ... }
```

Int your case of `mxArray *plhs[]` and `mxArray **plhs` this is the same logic. But, instead of `int`

- `mxArray *plhs[]` is an array of pointers to mxArray
- `mxArray **plhs` is a pointer to a pointer to a mxArray

Comment: “*if there is a slight difference here, is that the compiler uses directly the address of arr, while it takes the value of p (there is an indirection).*” I don’t understand what you are saying here. The two are identical and produce identical code. It’s just different syntax for the same thing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hi Cris. I tried to explain the sentence in the answer, please give it a look.

Comment: Yes, `Int arr[5]` is a static array, the compiler knows the location of each element, the pointer `arr` is never actually stored. But that doesn’t apply to OP’s case. I think that is why I was confused by the explanation. Thanks for clarifying!